# Apache: Allow only certain http requests, deny all else

Tags: apache-2.2, http, https

We have an Apache server, on a Windows Server 2008 machine, that is used for specific secure traffic for our customers, like a gateway.

Now, I only want to allow traffic for a certain range of secure URLs, defined by a wildcard uri:  ****secure.mysite.com****, and deny all other http or https request to Apache

How do you set that up in the Apache httpd conf file?

Thank you

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. If someone goes to paypal.com, how are they anywhere near your Apache?

Comment: Furthermore, what's 'secure' supposed to mean here? If you want to restrict traffic to certain URLs in a network, I'd rather use a transparent proxy server.

Comment: Do you have application logic hosted on your Apache httpd server that you want to allow access to or are you using httpd as a proxy?

Comment: I have edited my question...seems to be confusion with the url...

Answer (score 3):

You can [allow](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow) access via an environment variable that is only set via request URI patterns you want to match with [SetEnvIf](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html).

In your host, or virtualhost configure the following with the URI's you want to allow:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/requests/you/want/.* allow 
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/requests/you/want/.+?\.php$ allow
```

If you are serving the requests from Apache:

```
<Location /> 
 Order Deny,Allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from env=allow
</Location>
```

Or if proxying via [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#access), you probably want to combine the URI match with with some IP restrictions so you don't have an open proxy.

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr ^10\..+ deny

<Proxy *>
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from env=deny
 Allow from env=allow
</Proxy>
```

In this case, if the IP is *not* in the `10.0.0.0/8` range deny, [`Order`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#Order) being important